# Can't get Spring Websocket to work because of CompositeMessageConverter

Tags: spring, websocket

I'm trying to get Websockets and message brokers to work with Spring. I basically copy/pasted examples including the one from the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-annotations) but they won't work throwing the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter#0': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

This the XML that causes this exception:

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

None of the examples anywhere deal with creating a CompositeMessageConverter. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of websocket in my pom.xml. Changing to 4.3.1 fixed the problem.